# empty data frame returned if there are no rows which meet the condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a set of tables and the data in them changes. I need to remove some specific rows if there pass a condition, however in some cases, there are no rows to be removed. Instead of getting the whole data frame back I get an empty one. Here is a simplified example:

```
> data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
> a <- data.frame(data)
> b <- a[-(a$data==6),]
> b
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
> b <- a[-(a$data==8),]
> b
numeric(0)
```

How should I remove the lines, so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Using a minus and logical indexing is generally no good idea! `-c(T,F,T)` will become `c(-1, 0,-1)` which is probably not what you want. That said you may use the negation operator `!` instead of the minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
a[!(a$data==8),]
```

You may also want to use `drop=FALSE` to ensure the result is a `data.frame`:

```
> a[!(a$data==6),]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 7

> a[!(a$data==6),,drop=FALSE]
  data
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
7    7
```